# TF30063 error opening projects in Azure DevOps with a project already open connected to on-premises TFS server, or with Team Explorer tab selected

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfs

I am sometimes encountering "TF30063" errors in Visual Studio 2019 when connecting to an Azure DevOps (TFVC) repository.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (v16.1.4 at the moment) on a Windows 10 Pro (version 1809) workstation. This workstation previously had Visual Studio 2017.

We have a department repository at dev.azure.com, configured as a TFVC repository (not Git). This repository was originally created when Azure DevOps was VSTS, but we weren't using it for anything until recently, after it had been converted to Azure DevOps.

When opening a project that has its source managed in Azure DevOps in Visual Studio 2019, I have been encountering an error like this at times:

TF30063: You are not authorized to access dev.azure.com/[ORG-NAME]

Sometimes the error occurred when opening the project, and at other times when attempting to get the latest version of files or checking files in or out from the Azure DevOps repository.

I have been searching for this issue online for a few weeks, and have tried various suggested solutions, such as clearing the ".IdentityService" folder, or clearing out some specific AppData local/temp folders, or logging out of and back into Azure DevOps, etc. Some of these seemed to resolve the issue temporarily, but the issue always returned.

However, I now believe I know how to reliably cause this issue (and how to resolve it in the short term).

I have discovered that I can reliably cause this TF30063 error in either of two ways:

1. If I have Visual Studio open with a project connected to our on-premises TFS server, and then I open another instance of Visual Studio with a project that is connected to Azure DevOps.
2. If I don’t have any other projects open, but the last time that I had Visual Studio open, I left the "Team Explorer" tab selected (for example, because I had just checked in some files), and I open a project connected to Azure DevOps.

In either of the above cases, I will encounter the TF30063 error when I open a project connected to Azure DevOps (either when I first open the project, or when I attempt to perform any source control operations). In either case, the solution is relatively simple, as follows:

1. If Visual Studio is showing the "Team Explorer" tab/panel, select the "Solution Explorer" tab/panel.
2. If Visual Studio had already been showing the "Solution Explorer" tab, select the "Team Explorer" tab and then select the "Solution Explorer" tab again.
3. Make sure that the "Solution Explorer" tab is currently selected, and close this instance of Visual Studio (if I have other Visual Studio instances open that are connected to the on-premises TFS server, I can leave those open).
4. Re-open the same project (connected to Azure DevOps) in Visual Studio, and now everything seems to be fine.

Does anyone else have any additional information on this TF30063 error with Azure DevOps repositories, or any additional suggestions for resolving or working around the issue?

Comment: If anyone else can reproduce this issue with VS2019 connecting to an Azure DevOps repository, I would appreciate it if you could add a comment here to let me know. When connected to an Azure repository, select the "Team Explorer" tab, close VS2019, then re-open VS2019 with the same project and attempt any source control operation (such as "Get Latest Version"), and see if you get the TF30063 error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below and see if it helps.

- Close all instances of VS
- Delete %localappdata%.IdentityService
- Restart VS

another approach:

- Close all VS instances.
- delete your VS appdata folder and then open VS

Though this will reset all your setting. Hope it helps.

If you still face the same issue , please raise a request in below link.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8

you can do it from here too:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. As I mentioned briefly, I had already tried deleting everything in the ".IdentityService" folder, and also in the appdata folder (more than once for each). This sometimes/often makes it work again temporarily, but I now believe that was coincidence. Having the "Team Explorer" tab as the last selected tab, or having a local TFS project open when opening a project from Azure DevOps seems to be the underlying cause that can (at least for me) consistently reproduce the problem.
I did also open an issue at the link you included. Thanks.

Comment: This is the issue that I opened at the developercommunity site: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/630870/tf30063-authorization-error-when-opening-projects.html